# C# Appium WEBVIEW not recognized in android device

Tags: c#, android, selenium, webview, appium

I have a hybrid app that im currently testing using appium C#. This code runs with no problem in an emulator but when i run on an actual android device the webview part is not being recognized by appium and appium returns this error message:

> info: [debug] Available contexts: NATIVE_APP
>    info: [debug] []
>    info: [debug] Available contexts: NATIVE_APP
>    info: [debug] Responding to client with error: {"status":35,"value":{"message":"No such context found.", ...

I am using driver.Context = "WEBVIEW";
Does anyone know why this context is not being recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set "setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled" property in your android App to true. This is only required when the tests are run on real device.